# scraping website with requests, turning javascript variable data into python object

Tags: python

I am scraping a webpage that has a bunch of relevant information stored in a javascript variable

```
response = requests.get('')
r = response.text
```

inside `r`, there is a javascript variable that has a bunch of data I want

This is what is returned from the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
....

<script>
 var candidate_details_input_string =  = '{ ...}'
</script>
....
</head>
</html>
```

Inside `candidate_details_input_string` is a bunch of stuff and I use `.split()` to isolate the list I want

```
x = r.split('candidate_completed_list\\":')[1].split(']')[0]+']'
```

However, this returns the javascript string, but I'm in Python. It looks something like this:

```
x = '[{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Applicant_Information_Form\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2017-02-03T19:12:00.000Z\\"},{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Voluntary_Self_Identification_of_Disability_template\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2017-02-03T19:14:00.000Z\\"},{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Voluntary_Self_Identification_of_Disability_template\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2017-02-05T19:21:00.000Z\\"},{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Government_Entity_Questions_Form\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2018-07-03T00:29:00.000Z\\"}]'
```

This is a javascript string and normally would JSON.parse(), but can't since I'm scraping it in python.

Is there anyway to turn this into a Python object I can work with? My default answer is do it by hand, replace all of the `\\` and switch the `'` into `"`

Comment: Can you share the URL? There are various ways how to extract javascript variables from text.

Comment: its not a publicly accessible url unfortunately :(

Comment: updated with the <script> tag

Comment: its actually `{..}`, sorry!

Comment: Can you post sample whats inside the `'{...}'` brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your x variable into a json(dictionary). We need to replace those `\` and all is well:

```py
import json

x = '[{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Applicant_Information_Form\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2017-02-03T19:12:00.000Z\\"},{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Voluntary_Self_Identification_of_Disability_template\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2017-02-03T19:14:00.000Z\\"},{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Voluntary_Self_Identification_of_Disability_template\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2017-02-05T19:21:00.000Z\\"},{\\"i_form_name\\":\\"Government_Entity_Questions_Form\\",\\"completed_time\\":\\"2018-07-03T00:29:00.000Z\\"}]'

data = json.loads(x.replace('\\',''))

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` in this case:

```
data = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
....

<script>
 var candidate_details_input_string = '{"i_form_name":"Applicant_Information_Form"}';
</script>
....
</head>
</html>'''

import re
from ast import literal_eval

s = re.findall(r'var candidate_details_input_string\s*=\s*\'(.*?\})\s*\'\s*;', data, flags=re.DOTALL)[0]
data = literal_eval(s)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'i_form_name': 'Applicant_Information_Form'}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the `literal_eval(s)`. SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: @MorganAllen It would help if you post what's inside the string, to adjust the regex appropriately.

Comment: let me see if i can strip out the confidential information

Answer (score 0):

You're getting JSON back from requests.  Try using the built in json library of python, you shouldn't have to do any manual parsing yourself.

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('')
r = todos = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: im getting a string of HTML back from JSON that has some Javascript inside it. I get this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @Morgan isolate the json string like you've already been doing (or using an html parser to get to the value), _then_ pass it to `json.loads()`